# eigenfaces in scikit do not correspond to training images

Tags: python

I have code a small program of feature reduction by using PCA based on some online code, my source code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def main():
    lfw_dataset = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=100)
    n_samples, h, w = lfw_dataset.images.shape
    X = lfw_dataset.data
    y = lfw_dataset.target
    target_names = lfw_dataset.target_names
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
    n_components = 100
    pca = PCA(n_components=n_components, whiten=True).fit(X_train)
    X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
    plot(X_train,h,w)
    eigenfaces = pca.components_
    X_train_recover = pca.inverse_transform(X_train_pca)
    plot(eigenfaces,h,w)
    plot(X_train_recover,h,w)

def plot(images,h,w):
    n_row=2
    n_col=5
    plt.figure(figsize=(1.5 * n_col, 2.2 * n_row))
    plt.subplots_adjust(0.6, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5)
    for i in range(n_row * n_col):
        plt.subplot(n_row, n_col, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].reshape((h, w)), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The question that I have is when I execute the following lines of code:

```
eigenfaces = pca.components_
X_train_recover = pca.inverse_transform(X_train_pca)
plot(eigenfaces,h,w)
```

why the images that are plotted, eigenfaces, do not correspond to the set of images for training or the ones that I plot after the inverse_transform? I can see that the original training images and the ones from the inverse transform are the "same", if we consider that we had applied PCA.

For what I know pca.components_ will give me an array of n_components x  n_features, but I do not see the relationship with the original or the transformed images showed.

Any help?

Comment: AFAIK, `inverse_transform` just won't give you the original X. You can't get full information from projected data. check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com